# How to install iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus Simulator in Xcode 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, ios-simulator, xcode6

Is there any possible to install iPhone 6 and iPhone Plus Simulator in Xcode 5.1.1 ? And also i want to know, what is the lowest version of Deployment target in Xcode 6 ?

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't install the `iPhone` 6 simulators in `Xcode` 5 You Need Least deployment target in Xcode 6 is iOS

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't install the iPhone 6 simulators in Xcode 5, you'll have to update to Xcode 6. Least deployment target in Xcode 6 is **iOS 4.3**, the Xcode version doesn't have anything to do with the deployment target.

[image: Screenshot taken in Xcode 6] (Screenshot taken in Xcode 6)